# Is there a way to use only one namespace qualifier when importing modules in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a module

**src/lib.rs**

```
pub mod vk {
    pub struct Instance { /* ... */ }
}
```

And some code that uses the module

**src/examples/test.rs**

```
extern crate vk;

// What "use" statement do I put here?

fn main() {
    let x = vk::Instance::new();
}
```

I'd like to use `vk::Instance` but none of the use statements I try seem to work:

```
use vk::*;
use vk::vk;
use vk::{Instance};
use vk;
```

I *can* do the following, but is there a way to only need to use `vk::Instance` ?

```
use vk::vk::*;
let x = Instance::new();

let x = vk::vk::Instance::new();
```

Comment: If your crate is named `vk`, you don't need to wrap everything into a module `vk` in your `libr.rs` - the crate name(space) is prefixed to your names by default.

Comment: @Stefan, ah, that's it, thank-you!